# Checkbox always send 0 to database

Tags: php, forms

I am try to send my checkbox value to my database if it's checked value "Yes" else if not checked value "No"

I try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hidesCompany" id="hidesCompany" class="checkBoxStyle" value="Yes">
```

and this the PHP to post

```
$hidesCompany = $_POST['hidesCompany'];
    if($hidesCompany !='Yes'){
        $hidesCompany='No';
    }
```

but the problem here it always go to database as '0' not 'yes' or 'no'

Comment: what type of column is it in the database? Probably worth adding what database engine you are using as a tag. You should also use a hidden input of the same name (before the checkbox tag) so that when it's not checked a value is still submitted via the form, then you don't need to worry about that `if` in your php script.

Comment: Thanks @martincarlin87 Yes it was my fault I forgot about the database type it was 'int' by the way I didn't add hidden input of the same name (before the checkbox tag) but it's working fine is there is any problem to leave it like that.

Comment: nope, no problem with either approach, just comes down to personal preference really, I will add an answer for future reference aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the `hidesCompany` column in your database table has some kind of `INT` type rather than being `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` etc.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
$hidesCompany = '';
if(isset($_POST['hidesCompany']) && !empty($_POST['hidesCompany'])) 
{
    $hidesCompany = $_POST['hidesCompany'];

}
else
{
    $hidesCompany='No';
}
```

Comment: you need to check your checkbox is checked or not